# асинхронное обращение к микросервису из разных клиентов

Tags: веб-программирование, архитектура, request

Дано:
1) микросервис на asp .net core, web api, который выполняет тяжелую задачу
2) клиенты в виде мобильного приложения, ботов в соц сетях, сайта asp net mvc

Требуется:
Выполнять тяжелую задачу сервиса для клиентов асинхронно.
Иметь возможность подключать новых клиентов.

Видение:
Микросервис агрегатор, который получая новый запрос, сохраняет нужную информацию в rabbitmq, тяжелая задача выполняется для каждого нового сообщения в очереди, результат попадает в очередь.
Агрегатор - для каждого готового результата оповещает клиентов.

Вопрос:
Как реализовать такое оповещение? Нужно для каждого клиента сохранять в сервисе агрегаторе информацию из request? или передавать дополнительно агрегатору url обратного вызова?

Правильный ли такой подход вообще?

Comment: Как клиенты с сервисом общаются?

Comment: около всего этого развернуто amqp rabbitmq, поэтому клиент подписывается на событие очереди, при этом приходится для каждого нового клиента реализовывать тот же подход что неудобно и тем более не всегда возможно. Хочется делегировать общение с очередью на другой сервис, а клиент должен уже получать результат от этот сервиса.

Comment: какой протокол используют клиенты для общения с сервисом?

Comment: все взаимодействие через https

Comment: вы знаете, что http(s) это синхронный протокол? Сервер не может инициировать соединение.

Comment: Да, поэтому асинхронность достигается на более высоком уровне абстракции, не на уровене протокола, а на уровне очереди

Comment: это совсем другое. Какую абстракцию вы собираетесь поместить сверху http(s)?

Answer (score 0):

В целом, вы думаете в правильном направлении, но есть нюансы. RabbotMQ или другой брокер не должен "хранить" информацию - это шина данных, а не хранилище. Задача брокера передать событие, а тяжёлая обработка и сохранение результата это уже задача сервиса-получателя.

В целом, правильным решением вашей задачи будет примерно следующая схема:

1. Веб-апи получает запрос с параметрами задачи от клиента, сохраняет себе и публикует в шину событие ITaskCreated.
2. Микросервис тяжёлой обработки получает событие с параметрами задачи и начинает обработку.
3. После завершения обработки, микросервис публикует событие ITaskCompleted с результатами обработки.
4. Сервис веб-апи получает событие, достаёт результат и сохраняет результаты в задачу.

Таким образом, клиент получает и задачу и результаты с одного и того же сервиса, в то время как тяжёлый процессинг задачи выполняется на отдельных ресурсах. При этом важно, что клиенты никак не общаются с брокером и ничего не знают про его существование - узнать о завершении задачи клиент может разными способами, начиная от простого опроса веб-апи и закачивая обновлением по протоколу websocket.